# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at ):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am following Rails Tutorial on Chapter 10.
Since I do not have credit card, I am trying to send the email in development. I am newbie to programming, so I just want to see how it works.

But, I am getting this error.

```
    Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
    ):
      app/models/user.rb:65:in `send_password_reset_email'
      app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:13:in `create'

  Rendered /home/budi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (5.3ms)
  Rendered /home/budi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendered /home/budi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /home/budi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /home/budi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (30.9ms)
```

could somebody show me where I missed?

development.rb

```
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => 'mail.google.com',
    :user_name            => ENV['#I hardcoded it here'], # I put my my email which I used regularly here.
    :password             => ENV['#I hardcoded it here'], # I put the password here.
    :authentication       => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
```

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end

  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Password reset"
  end
end
```

application_mailer.rb

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  #default from: "from@example.com"
  default from: "xxxxxx@gmail.com" # I put my my email which I used regularly here.
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

password_reset_controller.rb

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_user,         only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user,       only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :check_expiration, only: [:edit, :update]

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
        @user.create_reset_digest
        @user.send_password_reset_email
        flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if params[:user][:password].empty?
        @user.errors.add(:password, "can't be empty")
        render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        log_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'edit'
    end

  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def get_user
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  end

  # Confirms a valid user.
  def valid_user
    unless (@user && @user.activated? && @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  # Checks expiration of reset token.
  def check_expiration
    if @user.password_reset_expired?
        flash[:danger] = "Password reset has expired."
        redirect_to new_password_reset_url
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: the problem is solved by turning ON the less secure apps option in sender email. I do not know whether it is a good practice or not. But it works for now. thanks!

Comment: Completely forgot to mention ha ha .. :) glad it solved Finally ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggests you to follow up with

- [Railsapps -Send Mail](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-send-email.html) and
- [Railsapps -rails-environment-variables](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html)

Would Definitely help You

*Edit Update*

[Allow less secure apps to access accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en)

> Google may block sign-in attempts from some apps or devices that do
>   not use modern security standards. Since these apps and devices are
>   easier to break into, blocking them helps keep your account safe.
>
> Some examples of apps that do not support the latest security
>   standards include:
>
> - The Mail app on your iPhone or iPad with iOS 6 or below The Mail app
> - on your Windows phone preceding the 8.1 release Some Desktop mail
> - clients like Microsoft Outlook and Mozilla Thunderbird

Comment: I delete ENV[ ] in user_name and password like suggestion from Rajarshi Das.

it gave me this error:

Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsly
):

Answer (score 2):

Hope you do not set user name and password in environment variable `ENV` instead you write it `ENV["the actual user name"]`

so it did not pass that.

and try gmail.com if you want to sent it via gmail

You can use

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "gmail.com",
    :user_name            => "test@gmail.com" #your gmail id
    :password             => "1234" #your gmail password
    :authentication       => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

or if you want to set the password in env

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "gmail.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

> If you’re familiar with Unix, you’ve likely had experience setting
>   environment variables. Unix environment variables are typically set in
>   a file that is read when starting an interactive shell (the ~/.bashrc
>   file for the bash shell).
>
> For a bash
>   shell,  edit the ~/.bashrc file and add:

```
export GMAIL_USERNAME="myname@gmail.com" 
export GMAIL_PASSWORD="mypassword"
```

Comment: restart ? the app use `gmail.com` check your gmail and pssword

Comment: restart ? the app use gmail.com check your gmail and pssword

Comment: it gave me this error:

Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/Conti
):

Comment: should I used " or ' like "mypassword" or 'mypassword'?

Comment: you could use either syntax no issue -

Comment: I did restart and change " and '. It still gives me that error.

Btw, I hard coded the email and password because I am not really familiar with unix. I am on Ubuntu Linux.